# Como obtener ancho y alto de una imagen a traves de un input file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estimados agradeceria su ayuda. Estoy tratando de obtener el ancho y el alto de una imagen cargada en un input-file de tipo multiple, para ello estoy implementando la siguiente funcion, pero siempre me devuelve como ancho y alto 0

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg" name="imagenes[]" id="imagenes" multiple>    

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#imagenes').change(function(){
            var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imagen = document.getElementById("imagenes").files;
            for(x = 0; x < imagen.length; x++){
                var imagen = imagen[x];
                var img = new Image();                  
                img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(imagen);
                var ancho = img.width;
                var alto = img.height
                console.log(ancho+' '+alto);
            }
            
        });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu error es muy simple, una imagen no se carga de forma instantánea en cuanto le asignas el src, tienes que asignar el evento onload, para poder usarla cuando ya se termino de cargar el recurso.

```
img.onload = function(){}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imagenes').change(async function () {
        var imagen = document.getElementById("imagenes").files;
        for (x = 0; x < imagen.length; x++) {
            loadImage(imagen[x]);
        }
    });
});
function loadImage(imagen) {
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(imagen);
    img.onload = function () {
        var ancho = img.width;
        var alto = img.height
        console.log(ancho + ' ' + alto);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg" name="imagenes[]" id="imagenes" multiple>
```

Comment: muchas gracias estimado, efectivamente me faltaba esa linea en mi codigo

Comment: Estimado, eh puesto en ves de console.log un alert, pero resulta ser que en todos los alert salen las medidas de la primera imagen seleccionada

Comment: Te edite la respuesta, únicamente saque la carga de la imagen a una función externa

Comment: Referido a load, @EduardoJaramilloLicea le podemos dejar este enlace al OP para que profundice: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-load

Comment: Me a servido mucho tu ayuda, mi duda es la siguiente estoy realizando la validacion de las dimensiones de las imagenes, quiero que si el ancho de la imagen es menor a 1200px no se pase ningun archivo al input file, o en su defecto el input quede vacio